# Vue AWS Amplify fail to get credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, authentication, credentials, aws-amplify

i am using AWS Amplify for authentication in a Vue app.

i am able to login successfully but cannot get credentials using Auth.currentUserCredentials() and Auth.currentCredentials().

i'd appreciate any help to sort out the problem.

i use Amplify's Hub event listener to listen to the auth channel for authorization events and the logger to debug.

on signing in, i notice this:

[image]

this is running in developer mode but exact same errors appear if built and run on website.

it seems that a POST to the localhost is causing the problem. but why does it call localhost when running a production build?

here's the whole log from signing in until after calling Auth.currentCredentials():

[image]

[image]

here's the code for the login form:

```
<amplify-authenticator>
  <div>
    My App
    <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
  </div>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

here's my aws-exports.js file:

```
const awsmobile = {
"aws_project_region": "eu-west-1",
"aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "eu-west-1:xyz....-4144-4b70-b021-e3486dbb1d43",
"aws_cognito_region": "eu-west-1",
"aws_user_pools_id": "eu-west-1_xyz....",
"aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xyz....",
"oauth": {}
```

};

export default awsmobile;

Answer (score 0):

seems there was a bug which has now been fixed so working now